# Can we create an iOS app without UIWindow?

Tags: ios, uiwindow

Can we create an empty iOS app without UIWindow. Need to create an dummy app without any ui window.

Comment: If all you want is a black screen, sure. It will never get into the App Store of course.

Comment: If you want a dummy app without any UI, just ignore the UI. Just because there is a default window and view and view hierarchy etc does not mean you have to do anything with it - will be probably not get into the appstore though

Answer (score 0):

You can. Just delete the view controllers in the storyboard file (usually Main.storyboard or MainStoryboard.storyboard) and then you won't have anything on the screen.

Also notice if you did not create a Single View app, you can start with an Empty app in Xcode create project window.

But this app will never take its way to the App Store.